# Create aura:attribute with a dynamic type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura, automation

I am attempting to put a custom lightning component **into a flow**, and I need a record collection variable. The problem is that I don't know what object the record collection variable is, and flows don't support the "Object[]" type. What can I do to make it dynamic, or is there no way?

Comment: Have you tried just declaring the type as `List`?

Comment: Or as a list of SObject?

Comment: Apart from what Adrian and Phile have mentioned, there is a quite nice documentation explaining [How Variable Types Operate in the Lightning Component Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/how-variable-types-operate-in-the-lightning-component-framework.html)

Comment: Using type `List` is not supported in Flows, otherwise I would try that. Does using type `sObject[]` allow me to use a record collection variable?

Answer (score 0):

Lightning aura component attribute of data type `Object` has some bug - properties of Object does not update in some cases. Instead other types like `sObject` or `Account` or `MyObject__c` works fine.

Other completely generic data types which work fine are `List` and `Map`.

1. List is array of any data type.
2. Map is Key-value pairs of any data-types. It is better if key is of type String.

You can define the type as `List` and try.